# Jmeter - Real time report with in Java webapp

Tags: java, json, jmeter

I want to generate a real-time (dynamic with delay) report with my own interface written with java. For every second, new point will be added to the chart. 
Currently, my workflow to generate a chart with Jmeter engine was Jmeter run -> JTL file -> JSON file -> Chart.
The problem is at the stage Jmeter run -> JTL and JTL -> JSON file, the write method will lock the file and the file will unable to read. This problem make the app runs really unstable.
So how can I solve this, any better solution for my case. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this? http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html

Comment: instead of converting JTL file JSON files, I suggest using backEnd Listener, store the results in `influxdb` and write continuous queries on top of it to plot the graphs. you can also evaluate `grafana server` which do the same job, but predefined graphs. refer the URL mentioned in the first comment

Comment: First thanks for your answers, seem that both of your solution was the backend listener. In my case, I want to create complete new dashboard which can execute independently with the Jmeter GUI. So is it possible for me to use and configure Backend listener from java code?

Comment: I d like to advertise my repo https://github.com/v0devil/jltom . I try to write online dashboard on Python. I use pandas to parse big csv file with test data and plot them using c3 graphs

Comment: Nice work @v0devil ! So technically you're using Pandas library to parse generated csv file, right? So how you deal with the real-time progress? And what if many users try to execute test at the same time?

Comment: @KhánhBùiNguyễnThiện
Yes I use pandas, this part is under development, but the idea is to track the number of lines which was parsed and with graph update we need to parse only part of file which was added since the last parse.  At this time it`s not possible to run the same test cuz I am blocking tests in jenkins if there is one running =). But for different tests there are different jobs in jenkins - it`s not a problem.

Comment: That's the point @v0devil ! When new lines were added, the system must read and write a same file, simultaneously. That may cause interruption and the updating chart was not stable. How you serve that problem? I plan to convert data from jtl to influxdb then use db to draw chart as well as calculations.